# Removing from linked list C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete a node, if x currently matches a int in my linked list.

I tried this, but once it removes the node it throws an error when examining foreach loop

```
public void DeleteNode(int x, LinkedList<name> myLinkedList) {
    foreach (name item in myLinkedList) {
         if (item.num.equals(x)) mylinkedList.Remove(x);
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can't use a `foreach`, need to switch to a `for`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you can't iterate over a collection and modify it at the same time. However, `LinkedList<T>` lets you do the iteration explicitly pretty easily:

```
public void DeleteNode(int x, LinkedList<name> myLinkedList) {
    var node = myLinkedList.First;
    while (node != null) {
        var nextNode = node.Next;
        if (node.Value.num == x) {
            myLinkedList.Remove(node);
        }
        node = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Note that you can't get away with just taking `node = node.Next;` as the last line; the node is invalidated when it's removed.

This approach allows a single traversal of the list in O(n), and is likely to be the most efficient approach you'll find. It doesn't require any copying, or working with a collection (say `List<T>`) with less efficient removal complexity.

Comment: This also has the advantage of being O(n) instead of O(n^2) considering the time complexity of `Remove(T)` versus `Remove(LinkedListNode<T>)`.

Comment: @RonWarholic: Absolutely. I'd assumed that was implicit, but I'll edit to state it :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, i'm still getting an error on the first part, i cannot convert a .LinkedListNode<T> to .LinkedList. My linked list is a collection of items, not just 1 int(although the int is the part i'm comparing)

Comment: @timmy: Which "first part"? Please identify which line of my code you mean, and the *exact* error. I'll edit my post to include the method declaration.

Comment: @timmy: And the exact error message? That should be absolutely fine. `myLinkedList` is a `LinkedList<T>`, and I'm just using the `First` property.

Comment: @JonSkeet var node = myLinkedList.First; I get an error on myLinkedList.first to say cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic to LinkedListNode to system.collections.generic.LinkedList

Comment: @timmy: That shouldn't happen if you're really using `var` - did you try to give `node` an explicit type? The code *exactly as I've written* compiles fine. What version of C# are you using? If you still can't get it working, please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem - because as I say, the code I've posted compiles fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry Jon, your code is right. I tried to use my type instead of var. Thanks!

Comment: @JonSkeet, I came across this post searching google, and am trying to figure out: why not just use foo.Remove(foo.First(x=> x.foo==bar))? It seems that First() is implemented to iterate over the list anyway, and so should result in the same code executing, but doesn't require writing this method you provided in this post?

Comment: @dferraro: No, because a `LinkedList<T>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>` - it just implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Additionally, my method removes *all* entries matching the given value.

Comment: @Jadoon: `LinkedList<T>` doesn't claim to be thread-safe to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet How should I go about it then, using minimum locking. Moreover I want to delete ,multiple items at once

Comment: @Jadoon: You should either look for a thread-safe collection, or perform appropriate locking, basically...

Answer (score 0):

If you call remove during a `foreach` it will invalidate the enumerator, so this is not allowed.

Change your `foreach` to a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I usually create a temporary collection and add it to it if it needs to be deleted. Then I loop through that list removing it from the original.

Answer (score 0):

The way I write that, without invalidating the iterator, is:

```
foreach(var item in list.Where(w=>w.num.Equals(x)).ToArray())
   list.Remove(item);
```

Comment: That's what [Shlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) would do.

Comment: @Jon, to be fair, I doubt it really matters.. Of course I only use it for arrays, but the code is solid enough for any iterator type.

Comment: @Blindy: Do you think it's particularly unlikely to have a linked list of, say, 10,000 elements? That's not a huge collection - but the difference between O(n) and O(n^2) is pretty large at that point...

Comment: @Jon, this thing (mostly) grows worse relative to the number of items you're *deleting*, so if we're talking about a list that you delete tens of thousands of items often enough that you notice the difference, then yea, it's a bit unlikely.

Comment: @Blindy: It only takes deleting a few hundred items from a list of 10,000 items to cause a headache with this approach, IMO. Btw, I have really been bitten by something like this in the real world - ironically, a bit of code which was meant to be *optimizing* removing one collection from a set. I wasted an entire morning trying to work out where my code was wrong. Not *quite* the same situation, but the same sort of performance characteristic difference. I [blogged](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/07/29/there-s-a-hole-in-my-abstraction-dear-liza-dear-liza.aspx) about it...

Answer (score 0):

I remove Items from list in the following way:

```
for (int j = lst.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
   {
    var elem= lst[j];
    lst.Remove(elem);
    }
```

It looks very close to regular "foreach var elem in lst", which is the reason I like it.

I go from the end to the beginning cause otherwise you'll loose your indexing, and will need to track number of removed items.

Answer (score 0):

`info` is a class.

This will find through `linkedlist` and delete the first item who's `no` property value is `1`

```
LinkedList<info> infolist = new LinkedList<info>();

string todelete = "1";

info tmpitem = new info();
foreach (var item in infolist)
{
    if (item.no == todelete)
        tmpitem = item;
}
infolist.Remove(tmpitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ListNode RemoveElements(ListNode head, int val)
    {
    if (head == null) return null;
        head.next = RemoveElements(head.next, val);
        return head.val == val ? head.next : head;
        
    }
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer from Jon Skeet with **thirty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.